# 2 dimensional array simulation/comparison

Tags: php, arrays

i have the following lines...

```
$getmodels = array(
array('value' => 1, 'text' => 'Services'),
array('value' => 2, 'text' => 'Customers'),
array('value' => 3, 'text' => 'Operators'),
array('value' => 4, 'text' => 'Supports'),
array('value' => 5, 'text' => 'Guests'),
);
echo json_encode($getmodels);
```

now i tried to duplicate the result via table with its row content..

```
$db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
$model = $db_connection->query("SELECT id, name FROM vhclmodel ORDER BY name;");
$getmodels = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($model)) {
   $getmodels[] = array('value' => $row['id'], 'text' => $row['name']);

}
echo json_encode($getmodels);
```

i cant get same result, kindly help.. still a newbie. TIA...

Comment: What result do you get? How is it different?

Comment: One is ordered by id, the other will be ordered by name

Comment: @jszobody - 2nd is empty...

Comment: @markbaker - could you pls correct the 2nd coding that will match the result of the 1st one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing `msqli` with deprecated `mysql` functions. Use `$model->fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysql_fetch_assoc($model)`.

So try this:

```
$getmodels = array();
while ($row = $model->fetch_assoc()) {
    $getmodels[] = array('value' => $row['id'], 'text' => $row['name']);
}
echo json_encode($getmodels);
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Also as Mark pointed out in a comment, your manual array is ordering by id, whereas your DB query is ordering by name. If that's important, just change your query:

```
SELECT id, name FROM vhclmodel ORDER BY id
```

Comment: yay! me so happy :D thank you sir! gonna read more about not mixing things :D

Comment: i slept like a baby last night... just woke up to code again :) your answer has been marked :) thanks so much.